# An array of objects as an argument of a function error in c++

Tags: c++

I have a templated class Node and I want to create an array of its object and pass it to a function. How do I do that?

```
Node<char> w1, w2, w3, w4;
Node<char> **s1 = new Node<char>* [3];
s1[0] = &w1; s1[1] = &w2; s1[2] = &w3;
w4.meet_neighbors(s1);
```

where I have the following prototype before:

```
template<typename T>
void Node<T>::meet_neighbors(Node<T>**);
```

Probing to do it that way results in the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Node<char>::meet_neighbors(Node<char>**&)
note: candidates are: void Node<TW>::meet_neighbors(const Node<TW>**) [with TW = char] <near match>
```

which outcome I do not understand. Please help.

Comment: You haven't allocated memory for `s1`; while your error is not directly related to that, it is saving you from a core dump.

Comment: thank you, but it nevertheless doesn't solve the problem. any further hints?

Comment: Are you sure you have the `include`s correct? Have you tried putting the function declaration right above your function call to see if it works?

Comment: @Shahbaz yes, the problem is that the nearest candidate is `Node<T>::meet_neighbors(Node<T>**) [ where T = char ]` which is correct. I don't know why the compiler claims he needs a method with additional "&" in format.

Comment: The additional & is not important. If you have a `function(int)` it will be written as `function(int&)` when an error is given.

Comment: @Shahbaz so what is this error message all about then? I have no clue...

Comment: Beats me! C++ can get really tricky at times.

Comment: @Shahbaz Ohh, I see. My fault, in declaration I have `meet_neighbors(const Node<TW>**)` while I should have `meet_neighbors(Node<TW>** const)` since Node is modified and the array is the one constant. It wasn't quite straightforward from the error log though. However, thank you very much for making it clear that I shouldn't care for this additional "&" sign, that helped me a lot! Is there a way at Stackoverflow for me to give you any kudos for that?

Comment: Since you are being so generous, I will post it as an answer you can accept! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two functions are differenet, not because there is an additional `&` in the error log<sup>1</sup>, but because one of them is a `const` pointer while the other is not.

<sup>1</sup> In C++ error logs (at least g++), even `f(int)` shows as `f(int&)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
Node<char>** s1 = new Node<char>*[4];
s1[0] = &w1; s1[1] = &w2; s1[2] = &w3;
w4.meet_neighbors(s1); Node<T>::meet_neighbors(Node<T>**);
/*...*/
delete[] s1;
```

But you really should consider using some STL containers instead of arrays, like std::vector. You may notice that your `meet_neighbors()` function is unable to determine the size of array argument. You need either to pass some container to it or add an array size argument.

Comment: Please! Change `delete s1;` to `delete[] s1;`. God save all your previous code.

Comment: There's a typho here: "function must be declared as Node<T>::meet_neighbors(T**)" right? Because I will rather need Node<T>**... But then it would be exactly as I stated. If allocating memory to s1 was to solve it, it didn't.